# General question about different ways to entertain dogs

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would like to create a general question about different ways to entertain dogs following the example of this question about [vet treatment options](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18810/12501). Ideally, each answer should contain the instruction for one specific game or training. I'm hoping to collect ideas for:

- high maintenance dogs who have more energy than can be burned during a walk;
- alternatives to a walk for days with bad weather or for pet owners who cannot or don't want to walk their dogs regularly;
- activities for injured, disabled or old dogs.

Many behavioral problems are either caused by boredom or could be treated by engaging the dog in physically and mentally stimulating activities. Some examples of recent questions are:

[Why has my dog started running out of our yard?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23431/12501)
[How to stop my dog chewing on everything?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/22167/12501)
[My dog hurts himself](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21810/12501)
[Dog won’t stop looking at light reflection/shadows](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21153/12501)

The spectrum of behavioral problems is so broad that questioners who do browse existing answers before posting their question are unlikely to find the information or link it to their specific problem.
Ultimately, I want to refer questioners to this general question instead of repeating answers to different questions.

---

It's done. The post can be found [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23521/12501).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is great idea.

Wait a couple of days and see if my answer here gets up votes or down votes, to see if the community agrees with me.

P.S. I have been very impressed with the answers you have been posting, you're doing a great job.  If I have not said it before, welcome to the community.

Comment: Thanks, but repeating the same things over and over again gets really tiring and frustrating. Hence this proposal ;)